Alert in that code prevents the display of the image


    async function displayImageAndAlert(url1) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = url1;
        await img.decode();
        await document.body.appendChild(img);
        alert('What number do you see?');
    }
    displayImageAndAlert('https://placehold.co/200x133?text=1');



The alert in that code prevents the display of the image. I want the image to show up before the alert does.
